# Include Readme.md in HTML file

Tags: html, github

I have a static HTML page which I am hosting on a personal server. I have a README.md file which I am storing in a public GH repo. I'd like to automatically include the contents of the ReadMe on my local html page.

Basically, I want to be able to update the Readme file in the project repo and have updated instructions automatically displayed on the project website.

Any thoughts?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think you might need more than just HTML for that.  Perhaps look into using [ajax](http://teamtreehouse.com/library/ajax-basics) to request your external resource and insert it into your page...

Comment: I know how to include a local, html page using jQuery, but I cannot get anything working using a Readme.md file on GH.